# 'Ground' object has no attribute 'rect'

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to pygame and coding in general and I am getting an error message that is confusing me.

I want detect collision between my player sprite and any of the sprites in the Ground() class. I try to use spritecollideany but I am getting the error message 'Ground' object has no attribute 'rect.'

**My player class**

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = pygame.image.load("marioLeft.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midtop = (self.x, self.y))

    def Move(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += 5
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= 5

    def Draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
```

**My ground class**

```
class Ground(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        self.ground_surf = pygame.Surface((self.width, self.height))
        self.ground_rect = self.ground_surf.get_rect(midtop = (self.x, self.y))
        self.ground_surf.fill('White')

    def DrawGround():
        for entity in ground_sprites:
            screen.blit(entity.ground_surf, entity.ground_rect)
```

**The code that is giving me an error message.**

```
if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, ground_sprites):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.sprite.spritecollideany`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollideany) (and all other collision detection functions) uses the **`rect`** attributes of the [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) objects to detect the collision. So each object needs to have a `rect` attribute. A sprite should also always have an `image` attribute which is needed for [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw).

Change the class `Ground`:

```py
class Ground(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midtop = (x, y))
        self.image.fill('White')

    def DrawGround():
        for entity in ground_sprites:
            screen.blit(entity.image, entity.rect)
```